# End points on Myers algorithm

Tags: algorithm, diff

I am trying to understand the algorithm of Myers about the problem [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)/SES (shortest edit script) but do not understand what are the **end points** and then do not understand how we proceed with the algorithm.
Would someone know how explain it?

Here are links, one on [paper by Myers](http://xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) and the other to a ["summary"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42279/Investigating-Myers-diff-algorithm-Part-of) (very well done).

Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**The LCS/SES Algorithm**

```
Constant MAX ∈ [0,M+N]
Var V: Array [− MAX .. MAX] of Integer

V[1] ← 0
For D ← 0 to MAX Do
    For k ← −D to D in steps of 2 Do
        If k = −D or k ≠ D and V[k − 1] < V[k + 1] Then
            x ← V[k + 1]
        Else
            x ← V[k − 1]+1
        y ← x − k
        While x < N and y < M and a x + 1 = b y + 1 Do (x,y) ← (x+1,y+1)
        V[k] ← x
        If x ≥ N and y ≥ M Then
            Length of an SES is D
            Stop
Length of an SES is greater than MAX
```

---

**Definitions**

**D-path** This is a path that start from `(0, 0)` and uses exactly `D` non--diagonal edges, that is vertical or horizontal.

**k-diagonal** - this is the diagonal comprised of all points `(x, y)` such that `x-y=k`

**snake** - path consisting only of diagonal edges

---

What do we store in `V`? `V[k]` stores the row index of the endpoint of the furthest reaching path on k-diagonal. The path should start at `(0, 0)`.

Why do we do this? Remember that we want to find the path from `(0, 0)` to `(N, M )` which uses least amount of **horizontal** and **vertical** edges. So in a sense we are looking for minimum `D` such that there is a `D-path` that ends in `(N, M)`

What does **end point** refer to? It refers to the the last point of a `D-path`. We, particularly , are interested in the furthest reaching end points along each `k`-diagonal

Let's suppose we've calculated `V` for all `D-paths`, `D<=D'-1`. To update for all `D-paths`, `D<=D'` we use the fact:

> A furthest reaching D-path on diagonal k can without loss of
>   generality be decomposed into a furthest reaching (D − 1)-path on
>   diagonal k − 1, followed by a horizontal edge, followed by the longest
>   possible snake or it may be decomposed into a furthest reaching (D −
>   1)-path on diagonal k+1, followed by a vertical edge, followed by the
>   longest possible snake.